# Use of boolean in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a function in PL/SQL which checks if a particular `emp_id` exists or not which is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkEmpNo(eno numeric)
RETURN boolean IS
    emp_number number;
BEGIN
    SELECT emp_id INTO emp_number
    FROM emp;
    IF eno=emp_number
    THEN
        return true;
    ELSE
        return false;
    END IF;
END checkEmpNo;
```

The function compiles successfully, but when I try to run it as:

```
DECLARE
    exist boolean;
BEGIN
    exist=checkEmpNo(1);
    dbms_output.put_line(exist);
END;
```

it returns the error:

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

3. BEGIN
4. exist:=checkEmpNo(1);
5. dbms_output.put_line(exist);
6. END;
```

EDIT:

I also tried this:

```
DECLARE
    exist boolean:=true;
BEGIN
    if(exist=checkEmpNo(1))
    then
        dbms_output.put_line('true');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('false');
    end if;
END;
```

And it returns the error: `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows`

Comment: On a general coding note, you're passing in a parameter named eno that is supposed to be equivalent to emp_id. Use emp_id as the parameter name, and prefix it with the function name when you use it in a SQL statement (ie. emp_id = checkEmpNo.emp_id)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`dbms_output.put_line` is not overloaded to accept a boolean argument.  You can do something like

```
dbms_output.put_line( case when exist = true 
                           then 'true'
                           else 'false'
                        end );
```

to convert the boolean into a string that you can then pass to `dbms_output`.

The ORA-01422 error is a completely separate issue.  The function `checkEmpNo` includes the `SELECT INTO` statement

```
SELECT emp_id 
  INTO emp_number
  FROM emp;
```

A `SELECT INTO` will generate an error if the query returns anything other than 1 row.  In this case, if there are multiple rows in the `emp` table, you'll get an error.  My guess is that you would want your function to do something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkEmpNo(p_eno number)
  RETURN boolean 
IS
  l_count number;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*)
    INTO l_count
    FROM emp
   WHERE emp_id = p_eno;

  IF( l_count = 0 )
  THEN
    RETURN false;
  ELSE
    RETURN true;
  END IF;
END checkEmpNo;
```

Comment: For passers by, Oracle has always had a bit of a strange relationship with booleans.  But things are getting better in v23.  [This >>](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle//oracle-database/23/sqlrf/to_char-boolean.html) wasn't possible in 12c (and 19c, I think)

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively you can use the Oracle function `diutil.bool_to_int` to convert a boolean value to an integer: True -> 1, False -> 0.

```
dbms_output.put_line(diutil.bool_to_int(p_your_boolean));
```

Comment: 'DIUTIL.BOOL_TO_INT' is declared inside 'sys'.