# What is wrong with my PLSQL Boolean Function?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, boolean

I'm trying to create a simple function to determinate if an employee really exist in the table using his ID as parameter, but It's been 2 days and I can't found what is wrong with my code.
Yesterday I found some interests articles here (stackoverflow) but I still can´t understand Boolean Functions and Why I receive ORACLE ERROR ORA-06550 wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'. Thanks.

```
  FUNCTION  emp_val(
    p_empid employees.employee_id%TYPE
  )
    RETURN BOOLEAN
  IS
    v_tf PLS_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT 1
    INTO   v_tf
    FROM   employees
    WHERE  employee_id = p_empid;
    RETURN TRUE;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN
      NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
  END emp_val;
```

Also when I try to invoke the function into a PL/SQL block I received Oracle Error 06550.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  v_result BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  v_Result := finalp_pkg.emp_val(120);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_Result);
END;
/
SHOW ERRROS;
```

And here is the error message:

```
Error que empieza en la línea: 2 del comando :
DECLARE
  v_result BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  v_Result := finalp_pkg.emp_val(120);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_Result);
END;
Informe de error -
ORA-06550: line 6, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'
ORA-06550: line 6, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
No Errors.
```

Comment: Well, what does the documentation say about the type(s) of the argument(s) that put_line takes? Does your code match that?

Comment: Yes Mat, I've read about put_line data types but I don't know another way to print boolean expressions on console. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560040/use-of-boolean-in-pl-sql

Comment: Sorry for that. I really searched for other similar questions but I didn't find it. Thanks